# Tinytest meteor mocking

Tags: meteor

I tried to mock `Template.__create__` with the code below but I still get the error.

In package.js

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'robwatkin:mypackage',
});
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');

  api.use('meteor-platform');
  api.use('iron:router');
  api.use('reactive-var');
  api.use('templating');
});
Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.addFiles('mocks.js');
  api.use('robwatkin:mypackage');
  api.addFiles('tests.js');
});
```

in mocks.js

```
Template = {
    __create__: function() {console.log('STUB Template.__create__')}
};
```

in tests.js

```
Tinytest.add('example', function (test) {
  test.equal(true, true);
});
```

Gives

```
Uncaught TypeError: Template.__create__ is not a function(anonymous function) @ layout.js:286(anonymous function) @ iron_layout.js?d62e492972d7f97328c54d2ba052d5adf0cf0d9a:534(anonymous function) @ iron_layout.js?  d62e492972d7f97328c54d2ba052d5adf0cf0d9a:541
```

It works fine if I comment out

```
api.use('robwatkin:mypackage');
```

Thanks